# Array - find how many times an object repeats consecutively

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

My array objects are as follows:

```
10,10,10
20,23,14
10,10,10
10,10,10
10,10,10
32,23,42
32,23,42
10,10,10
32,23,23
32,23,23
```

How can I go through this array and find out how many times the same object repeats sequentially, then add a , and the number of times it repeats?

Then save a new array with objects like:

```
10,10,10,1
20,23,14,1
10,10,10,3
32,23,42,2
10,10,10,1
32,23,23,2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do the first and third instances of `10,10,10` get `,1` yet the second instance gets `,3`? Also, are these objects strings?

Comment: Because I only care about consecutive repeats.

Comment: Not total occurrences of an object.

Comment: Why the thumbs down?!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, so I can't say for sure. But I imagine that it's because your question shows no evidence that you tried anything before posting here.

Comment: What does  “the same object repeats sequentially, then add a , and the number of times it repeats” mean?   Please edit question to fix its problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *outArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [theArray count]; j++) {
    id object = [theArray objectAtIndex:j];
    NSUInteger repeats = 1;
    while (j + 1 < [theArray count] && [[theArray objectAtIndex:j + 1] isEqual:object]) {
        j++;
        repeats++;
    }
    [outArray addObject:object];
    [outArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:repeats]];
}
return outArray;
```

This can also be done in place if the input array is mutable.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: While this works, your runtime is O(J*N) (although N=3 here, it could be worse)

Comment: O(J*N) with J being any constant is still O(N).  And any solution that involves inspecting every element of the array is going to be at least O(N).

Comment: Right, but although this example is constant, someone looking at this algorithm could apply it to a variable J

Comment: @waf I'm still not understanding how it can be improved.  Surely the running time of *any* algorithm that involves scanning the array and comparing each element to the next element in the array is going to be proportional to the length of the array times the average running time of the comparison operation.  OP could reduce the comparison time by doing pointer comparison if that happened to be appropriate.  (I also want to point out that I think you're assuming the running time of `isEqual` is proportional to the length of the input strings, but the average case is probably faster.)

Comment: @waf - The run time is not O(J*N); it's O(J) (assuming that in your notation J is the length of the original array and N is the max rep count). Each iteration of the inner loop body decreases the outer loop iteration count by one, so they are in perfect balance.

Answer (score 0):

Break up every three integers into its own array (make sure they are strings).

Then iterate through each one of those arrays, and input into an NSMutableDictionary, the key is the string (your number), the value is a counter (if seen once, add 1, etc...)

Keep a pointer to the highest key (if newCount > highestCountPointer, then highestCountPointer=newCount)

At the end of that iteration, add the number that the highestCountPoints to to the end of the array.

Comment: OP only wants a kind of run-length encoding, not a list of unique values with counts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Objective C programmer, so please pardon any language gaffes. Something like the following should do the job:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
id pending = nil;
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [theArray count]; i++) {
    id object = [theArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([object isEqual:pending]) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (pending != nil) {
            [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d", pending, count]];
        }
        pending = object;
        count = 1;
    }
}
if (pending != nil) {
    [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d", pending, count]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run "uniq -c" from command line :)

Comment: OP isn't looking for unique counts, just a kind of run-length encoding.

Comment: Reformatting the result of "uniq -c" would give you "run-length encoding" (HINT: use sed or tr)